# Start void after x seconds

Tags: objective-c, function, cocos2d-iphone

How can I start a function after e.g. 10 sec?
I tried this but it does not work :(

```
-(void)callFunction:(CCTime)dt
{
NSLog(@"Calling...");
}

[self schedule:@selector(callFunction:) interval:10.0f];
```

But `CCTime` makes a error : "Expected a type"

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/3614171/2462469

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to call a method with delay](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9634790/how-to-call-a-method-with-delay)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `ccTime` not `CCTime`

```
-(void)callFunction:(ccTime)dt
{
   NSLog(@"Calling...");
}
[self schedule:@selector(callFunction:) interval:10.0f];
```